# NS_SWIFT_NAME base name verify error

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I have following code in my header file *Test.h*:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject

- (void)test NS_SWIFT_NAME(verify());

@end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

- (void)test {
    return;
}

@end
```

Then I try to import this interface to my swift source code, but I get following warning: **'swift_name' attribute has invalid identifier for base name** and swift name for this function is still *test*. Other names like *verif*, or *verify1* work just great.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`verify` is defined as a macro in `<usr/include/AssertMacros.h>`:

```
#ifndef verify
    #define verify(assertion) __Verify(assertion)
#endif
```

in terms of another macro `__Verify`. As a consequence, the compiler
preprocesses the definition to (as you can verify with
Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess "Test.m")

```
- (void)test __attribute__((swift_name("do { if ( __builtin_expect(!(), 0) ) { DebugAssert('?*?*', 0, \"Third Party Client\" \": \" \"\", 0, 0, \"/PathTo/Test.h\", 22, (void*)0); } } while ( 0 )")));
```

which is definitely not a valid Swift name.

Using a different name would be the easiest solution. Otherwise `#undef`ing the macro
is a workaround:

```
@interface Test : NSObject

#undef verify
- (void)test NS_SWIFT_NAME(verify());

@end
```